# C++ enum keyword in function parameters

Tags: c++, scope, declaration, name-hiding, elaborated-type-specifier

What is the point of using the `enum` keyword in the function parameter? It seems to do the same thing without it.

```
enum myEnum{
  A, B, C
};

void x(myEnum e){}

void y(enum myEnum e){}
```

Is there a difference between the two?

Comment: Probably C compatibility. C has different rules about when identifiers are treated as types and tends to require you be more explicit about using the `enum` and `struct` keywords. So for example in C [x doesn't compile](https://godbolt.org/z/8jMz4TPjf) and you actually need to write the `y` version. It doesn't hurt anything for C++ to maintain this compatibility with C syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this function declaration

```
void x(myEnum e){}
```

the enumeration myEnum shall be already declared and not hidden.

In this function declaration

```
void y(enum myEnum e){}
```

there is used the so-called elaborated type name. If in the scope there is declared for example a variable with the name myEnum like

```
int myEnum;
```

then using this function declaration

```
void y(enum myEnum e){}
```

allows to refer to the enumeration with the name myEnum that without the keyword enum would be hidden by the declaration of the variable.

Here is a demonstrative program.

```
#include <iostream>

enum myEnum{
  A, B, C
};

void x(myEnum e){}

int myEnum; 

//  compiler error
//void y(myEnum e){} 

void y(enum myEnum e){}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    return 0;
}
```

As it is seen the commented function declaration will not compile if to uncomment it.

Comment: Note (OT-ish): It's probably a good thing to mention C++11 enum classes. `enum class myEnum` gets its own scope and will lead to fewer surprises